# Definitive recommendation about pork-derived and alcohol-containing medications?

Tags: alcohol, medical, pork

I saw a lot of questions about the use of medications derived from pork. Here is one where the product itself is derived from pork : [Is it permissible to take a supplement that contains an ingredient derived from pork?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/21527/is-it-permissible-to-take-a-supplement-that-contains-an-ingredient-derived-from) And here is a different one where a substitute may be found, since the pork is only in the envelope : [Is vegetarian contents inside a gelatin capsule haram to use?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36789/is-vegetarian-contents-inside-a-gelatin-capsule-haram-to-use). The answers clearly advise not to take it unless it is in an emergency case.

I noticed that in the case of alcohol as a medication, the use seems permitted (see [Is there any exception that consuming alcohol or alcoholic foods is OK?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/410/is-there-any-exception-that-consuming-alcohol-or-alcoholic-foods-is-ok))

Is there any reason for this difference in treatment, or are the answers on the pork-based medications false?

Also, (this is more a meta question) shouldn't the answer automatically be "use your medication in the way your doctor wants you to"? It would be better for the health of the users...